# How to handle user's timezone and UTC sync between application and database in CakePHP?

Tags: php, datetime, cakephp, timezone, utc

I need to display dates and times in user's timezone. But I also need to save dates and times in UTC, so my database stay consistent.

My cakephp application configured like this:

**In config/app.php file:**

```
 'Datasources' => [
    'default' => [
        ...
        'timezone' => 'UTC',
```

**In config/bootstrap.php file:**

```
/*
 * Set server timezone to UTC. You can change it to another timezone of your
 * choice but using UTC makes time calculations / conversions easier.
 */
date_default_timezone_set('UTC');
```

In my application, a user can change his timezone whenever he wants. It's then saved in database and available as `$this->Account->timezone` in controllers, and `$account->timezone` in views.

So let's say my database is consistent and all my datetimes are stored in UTC, so when user type in a date, it's converted to UTC (from his timezone).

Now I want to display these dates. I get them from my database in UTC. For now I use the method from Cakephp (where `$item` is an entity and `date` is an attribute of this entity):

```
$item->date->i18nFormat('dd/MM',$user->timezone),
```

With this function I can easily display datetimes in the format I want, and in the timezone I want.

Is there a way to set `$user->timezone` to the entire app, so I don't need to specify it each time ?

Thanks.

Comment: Will all users be staying in the same timezone? and how are you deciding the timezone the users is currently in?

Comment: @Viney User can change timezone in their settings

Comment: Use timeHelper https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views/helpers/time.html#using-the-helper

Comment: How would you do that ? So I need to display each date with TimeHelper? By passing user's timezones in each call ?

Comment: Why do you feel like passing it as a parameter each time is wrong?  From an architectural perspective, who's to say that your app somewhere won't need to display values in two different time zones on the same page?

Comment: @MattJohnson Sure, I'm just asking for the best way to deal with user's timezone and dates and times displaying

Comment: I updated my question so it could be more understandable

Comment: @MattJohnson Sure it's not wrong, but maybe I can set a default value so I don't repeat myself ?

Answer (score 3):

Your question reads as if you're already handling the timezone conversion when saving user supplied dates, so I'll stick to the display part.

### Use the time helper

As stated in the comments, there's nothing wrong with explicitly passing the timezone whenever it is required, however if you'd really need to adjust the timezone for (mostly) everything you output in your view templates, then take a look at the (kind of undocumented) time helper's `outputTimezone` option.

```
$this->loadHelper('Time', ['outputTimezone' => $user->timezone]);
```

Then use the helper's `i18nFormat()` method and you should be good with regards to timezone conversion:

```
$this->Time->i18nFormat($item->date, 'dd/MM');
```

### Configure a global string format

It's also possible to globally configure the output format via the `\Cake\I18n\DateFormatTrait::setToStringFormat()` 
 and `\Cake\Chronos\Traits\FormattingTrait::setToStringFormat()` methods, which are available on the `Date/Time/FrozenDate/FrozenTime/Chronos` classes accordingly.

The following would for example cause all "date only" objects to be formatted as `dd/MM` when being converted to a string, being it through implicit casting, or explicit formatting when calling for example `i18nFormat()` without passing a specific format:

```
\Cake\I18n\Date::setToStringFormat('dd/MM');
```

### See also

- **[Cookbook > Views > Helpers > Configuring Helpers](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views/helpers.html#configuring-helpers)**
- **[Cookbook > Date & Time > Setting the Default Locale and Format String](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/core-libraries/time.html#setting-the-default-locale-and-format-string)**