# What's the point of timezone configuration in a CakePhp application?

Tags: php, cakephp, configuration, timezone

CakePhp allows to set timezone for Datasources (database) and for app in these two files:

In config/app.php :

```
'Datasources' => [
    'default' => [
        'className' => 'Cake\Database\Connection',
        'driver' => 'Cake\Database\Driver\Mysql',
        'persistent' => false,
        'host' => 'localhost',
        'timezone' => 'UTC',
        ...
    ]
]
```

In config/boostrap.php :

```
/*
 * Set server timezone to UTC. You can change it to another timezone of your
 * choice but using UTC makes time calculations / conversions easier.
 */
date_default_timezone_set('UTC');
```

What does it do exactly ?
Because when I save a Time in datetime column in my database, it doesn't even convert it to UTC...

So what's the point? How should this be used?

Thanks.

Comment: What if you have an application that will have clients from all over the world? Each one will have it's timezone and this will help the server knows from which time to guide from. Without this we would come back to before Greenwich's time `pun intended`

Comment: Change one of those `UTC`s to something else and see what it stores in your database.

Comment: Should I change this based on user's timezone then ? Cakephp advice not to do so If I understand well

Answer (score 3):

What exactly it does depends on the DBMS used, for MySQL it changes the `time_zone` setting (for that connection only), which affects so called "*zone-sensitive*" functions and data types, such as `NOW()` and `TIMESTAMP`. `DATETIME` type columns aren't affected, they are not zone-sensitive.

> The current session time zone setting affects display and storage of time values that are zone-sensitive. This includes the values displayed by functions such as NOW() or CURTIME(), and values stored in and retrieved from TIMESTAMP columns. Values for TIMESTAMP columns are converted from the current time zone to UTC for storage, and from UTC to the current time zone for retrieval.
>
> The current time zone setting does not affect values displayed by functions such as UTC_TIMESTAMP() or values in DATE, TIME, or DATETIME columns. Nor are values in those data types stored in UTC; the time zone applies for them only when converting from TIMESTAMP values. If you want locale-specific arithmetic for DATE, TIME, or DATETIME values, convert them to UTC, perform the arithmetic, and then convert back.

**https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/time-zone-support.html**

CakePHP currently does **NOT** *transform* timezones when reading/writing from/to the database.

The default PHP timezone set via `date_default_timezone_set()` will affect how CakePHP parses/interprets date/time values when they are being marshalled (this happens for example when creating/patching entities), and how CakePHP/Chronos date/time objects are being created.

See also

- **[Cookbook > Internationalization & Localization > Parsing Localized Datetime Data](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/core-libraries/internationalization-and-localization.html#parsing-localized-dates)**
- **[Cookbook > Date & Time](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/core-libraries/time.html)**
- **[Cookbook > Chronos](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/chronos.html)**

Comment: Thanks, this is really helpful ! I need to allow users to select their timezone, and then save / display datetime accordingly to it. What's the best way ? Shoud I set `date_default_timezone_set` ? Or do it manually on each datetime ?

Comment: @HJerem You're welcome. That would be something for a separate question. Unfortunately there's currently no overly clean way, or convention for that. You might want to edit your other timezone question and explain what exactly a "user" is in that context, and where and how exactly in the saving/displaying process things need to be transformed from what / to what accordingly.

Comment: I edited my other question [How to handle user's timezone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49280448/how-to-handle-users-timezone-and-utc-sync-between-application-and-database-in-c)
I hope it's clearer. I'm looking for the more convenient way to handle user's timezone, saving and displaying.